# How to get the name of input?

Tags: node.js, restify

```
<p>uploadFile１<input type="file" name="file1"/></p>
<p>uploadFile２<input type="file" name="file2"/></p>
```

In Asp.Net, I can do like this

```
HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
foreach( string key in files.AllKeys ) {
    HttpPostedFile file = files[key];
    if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName) == false )
       file.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + file.FileName)  
}
```

Does Node.js have any methods like `files.AllKeys` that can get the the values of "name" attribute of input.
Because I want to upload multi files to the server.

Comment: Are you using any library like Connect or Express or are you working directly with the `http` library?

Answer (score 0):

Use `restify.bodyParser()` before all your routes. You will then have access to the `files` object in your `request` object.

```
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

...

server.post('/upload', function (req, res, next) {
  var file1 = req.files.file1;
  var file2 = req.files.file2;

  ...
});
```